# Searching specific list within dictionary with lists as values in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary with strings as keys and lists as values. I now have another list (list2) and I would like to search if there are any dictionary values lists that contain all the items of list2. I would then like the output to be the key of the matching dictionary value list.

My code now looks something like this:

```
for elem in list2:
    for elem2 in dict.keys():
        if all(item in elem2 foritem in list2):
            print(elem2)

value_found_list = dict.get(elem2)

print(value_found_list)
```

Edit minimal reproducable example:

```
dict{
"key1": ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'], 
"key2": ['item2', 'item4', 'item5'],
"key3": ['item3', 'item6', 'item4']
}
list = ['item2', 'item3']
```

How would I with this data return which dictionary key contains all items in the list?

Comment: post example data and expected output. this is too abstract

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) What's wrong with your current code -- why doesn't it work? Or does it not give you the expected output? What is your expected output? What do you currently get?  Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and [ask], and provide a [mre]. When asking for help, the more _relevant_ details you give, the easier it is for others to help you. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: I added more of the program now!

Comment: You swung too far in the other direction. A [mre] needs to be _minimal_. Narrow down the source of the problem and post only relevant details. It's no fun parsing through line after line of code trying to find an unspecified error.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I put down a minimal reproducible example now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off changing your second `list` to a `set` if you're planning on doing membership checking.

Here's a short function that does just that.

Edit: Since you're doing it the other way around it's probably less time intensive to just use the list in your `dict`. However, It may make more sense to have them in the form of a `set` in the first place.
A `set` is hashed which translates to faster lookup time.
If your `list`s are pretty long, you'll save some computation time by having them in this form.

```
def get_key(dct, lst2):
    # iterate through every key and list
    for key, lst in dct.items():
        # if all the list items are present in your second list
        if all(i in lst for i in lst2):
            return key
    # default to returning None
    return None

dct = {
"key1": ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'], 
"key2": ['item2', 'item4', 'item5'],
"key3": ['item3', 'item6', 'item4']
}
lst = ['item2', 'item3']
print(get_key(dct, lst))
```

Where you were going wrong is here.

```
    for elem2 in dict.keys():
        if all(item in elem2 foritem in list2):
```

`elem2` is a string key. `item in elem2` is looking for the full string within the key.
`dict.values()` returns the values or lists that you were probably looking for.

However `dict.items()` returns the keys and values as a tuple which is probably what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Watch this

```
a = {'one':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'two':[5, 6, 7, 8], 'three':[9, 10]}
b = {'four':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'five':[6, 7, 8], 'six':[9, 10]}
for akey in a:
    for bkey in b:
        if a[akey] == b[bkey]:
            print(akey, bkey)
```

outputs:

```
one four
three six
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[i for i in your_dict if set(your_dict[i]).union(set(list2))==set(your_dict[i])]

print(l)
```

for:

```
your_dict={
"key1": ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'], 
"key2": ['item2', 'item4', 'item5'],
"key3": ['item3', 'item6', 'item4']
}
list2 = ['item2', 'item3']
```

The output is:

```
['key1']
```